# Add custom text in second paragraph of posts in specific category

Tags: categories, custom-field

I am trying to display following custom text in the second paragraph of each post lying under category 'Blue Screen' (cat_id 128133):

Helpful tools to research and fix:

1. BlueScreenView
2. Whocrashed
3. Restoro

This should be like below screenshot (content in the screenshot under red block should be replaced with the custom text):

[image: Add custom text in second paragraph of posts in specific category]

Any help would worth appreciation and obligation.